# Displaying steep slopes with use of Contours in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, contour, slope, topography

I am using Arc Map 10.1.  I have downloaded contour data as a shapefile.

Is there any way to use the contours to display steep slopes so 15%-25% or 25% and greater?

Comment: This may help with what you're looking for. 

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018p00000008000000

Comment: What a about using the raster calculator, after generating the slope raster?

Comment: how do you generate the slope raster from contours?

Comment: Some suggestions [here](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=983&t=265826).

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a slope raster - convert to polygons and use the resulting polygons to clip the contours then symbolize them differently.

Comment: Please provide more detail.